# Angular - Verify url parameters on service

Tags: angular, url, routes, url-validation

Good day,

I have an `angular` application with the following routes:

```
orders/123
orders/123/lines
messages/123
messages/123/lines/new`
```

I have a lot more routes then this and a lot more entities.

I want to verify that the id `orders/**:id**` is a valid id of an existing order. If so I want to show the page and if not i want to redirect to a general **404 page**.

I have a lot of entities so I would like to solve this as generally as possible.
What is a good way to approach this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can do a simple if in the oninit page, or a router guard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the id in the ngOnInit event with ActivatedRoute from '@angular/router'
and create a method which check if the entity exists serverside.

If not you can navigate to your 404 page with the Router from '@angular/router':

this.router.navigate(['/your-404'])